# Power Iteration method for eigenvalues - Show the error is bound

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, asymptotics, inner-products

Let $A \in $Sym$_{n}(\mathbb R)$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ such that $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2| \geq |\lambda_3 |\geq ... \geq |\lambda_n|$

We define the following process as "Power Iteration":

1) choose any $u^{(o)} \in \mathbb R^n$

2) for $k\geq 0$: $$u^{(k+1)}=\frac{Au^{(k)}}{||Au^{(k)}||}$$

Show that $\langle u^{(k)},Au^{(k)} \rangle$ converges to $\lambda_1$ and that the error is $O(|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}|^{2k})$

I managed to show convergence. $u^{(k)}$ converges to the normalized eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$ and so that inner product converges to $\lambda_1$, but I don't know why the error is bound by that value.

What I did:

write $u^{(o)}$ in the basis of orthonormal eigenvectors of A which we know exists since $A$ is symmetric:

$$A^ku^{(0)} = A^k \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_iv_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda^k_i \alpha_iv_i = \lambda^k_1\alpha_1(v_1+\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\frac{\lambda^k_i}{\lambda^k_1}v_i)$$

since $\lambda_1$ is largest, as $k$ approaches infinity, the term in the parenthesis converges to $v_1$, and so $A^ku^{(0)} = \alpha_1\lambda^k_1v_1$, and $u^{(k+1)} = =\frac{Au^{(k)}}{||Au^{(k)}||} = \frac{\alpha_1\lambda^k_1v_1}{||\alpha_1\lambda^k_1v_1||}=v_1$

it follows that the inner product converges to $\lambda_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** expand the value of $u^{(0)}$ along the basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Yes. That's how I proved convergence. I still don't see how to infer the error...

Comment: In order to help you with that, it would help me to see your proof of convergence. Do you mind editing your question with the outline of the proof?

Comment: done ^^ thank you. I edited what I did. Where do we go now?

Comment: Using the orthogonality of the basis vectors, you can simplify $\langle u^{(k)}, Au^{(k)}\rangle$ to get a simple sum.